# Disable Fetch on Hibernate joinColumn

Tags: hibernate

We're using Spring Boot + Hibernate, one of our classes has joined column with FetchType.EAGER. We would like to disable the fetch (simply return empty for that column), but after commenting out ElementCollection and CollectionTable, I cannot compile with the following error:

```
//@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
//@CollectionTable(name = "gsf_locate_request_pth", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "locate_id")})
@Column(name = "pth_ref")
private Set<Long> payToHoldRefs;


Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: gsf_locate_request, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(pth_ref)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Annotation `@Column(name = "pth_ref")` for simple types like `String` only. Hibernate try to put `Set<Long>` in  one table column. It is impossible, of course.  Just use `FetchType.LAZY`

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@CollectionTable(name = "gsf_locate_request_pth", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "locate_id")})
private Set<Long> payToHoldRefs;
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can just simply disable the fetch (not LAZY as well)?

Comment: @enfany Don't know. Another way is  loading an object using projections.